# my custom css file downloads then it STOPS!

Tags: user-registration, wp-enqueue-style, css, wp-register-style

I’m watching an online course for WordPress development and at the beginning I attached the css file the exact like what the instructor did and tested it by adding some styles and it worked fine

Then when I start making some menus in the `header.php` the css file stops when I checking it with dev tool by chrome, the `style.css` is exist in “sources” but it’s empty even if I’m sure that the style.css isn’t empty 
I tried to watch the whole course again to apply every single line and got the same problem and I tried to delete the xamp and reinstall it and the same problem

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're missing a slash »/« before style.css.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "it stops"? I can think of multiple things that could be ranging from a PHP syntax error, to broken CSS. Being able to see the contents of `header.php` would be helpful. Also, what's the name of the file shown in your screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all you need is to add a trailing slash so the directory is correct.

Solution: change `'style.css'` to `'/style.css'` in your second `wp_register_style()` call on line 7.